# I am looking for a story of gods/deities creating a world, then assigning a boy to name everything in that world

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to identify a 'Creation myth' story I read from childhood that seems to stump Library of Congress librarians and local librarians. I've also used reddit, Abebooks booksleuth, Loganberry books 'book finder', goodreads forums, and more.

The story begins with many gods/deities in the universe that have just finished creating a world, and they are quarrelling amongst each other because no object or creature in the world was given a name yet. So the deities decide to create a boy (or assign a boy, I don't remember exactly how they pick the boy) in the newly created world the task of naming everything for them. Thus, the boy goes on many adventures travelling to distant places and giving names to everything.

So for example, if the boy came across an object or creature, he would ask the gods "What is this called?" and they would respond something like "That's up to you to decide" along those lines.

The author could have had influence or have been inspired by foreign creation stories/myths/legends (Indian/Arabic, possibly Greek/Persian/Chinese?). It is also possible that the book could have been translated into English from another language.

The copy I had was a hardback may have had a dustjacket, color was offwhite with decent spine thickness ((roughly 5/5.5 x 8" dimensions, about .5" thick). It was published before 1998, and could be from any decade before the 90s. The cover was colorful, featuring an illustrated image of the boy looking down on a cloud, with short black hair, wearing white
(his eyes are looking downward) with a celestial background I've drawn an image from memory of the cover. It may
not be 100% but I know for sure the boy had black hair and was featured on the cover.
The gods may have been elemental gods (god of wind, thunder, etc), so you will notice lightning,
wind, and little details to represent the elements. Backdrop is celestial, featuring the moon, stars, etc.

[image]

If any story with a similar premise comes to mind, please post! If its similar, it may be it!

Comment: Good question. One possible improvement: maybe you could include links to your queries on Abebooks, Goodreads, etc.? So we can see what suggestions have already been made, and won't have to repeat them.

Comment: Have you tried the newsgroup [rec.arts.sf.written](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rec.arts.sf.written)? Maybe it's included in your "and more"; if not, it's worth a try.

Comment: Neverending Story requires the boy to wish into being many parts of the world.

Comment: [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1448183-fantasy-children-s-story-from-80s-90s---gods-create-a-boy-prince-to-name), [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/16813952-gods-create-world-and-then-create-boy-to-give-animals-objects-names), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/3e8nsj/any_help_finding_a_book_for_a_customer/), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/childrensbooks/comments/34b0jq/lost_book_from_childhood_fantasymythological/), and [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/topic/157775) queries for reference.Not Neverending Story or Little Prince

Comment: The query has appeared in AbeBooks forums [here](http://tinyurl.com/panonh7), [here](http://tinyurl.com/nl22blh), [here](http://tinyurl.com/oghs3ds), [here](http://tinyurl.com/nj2hh6d), and [here](http://tinyurl.com/oxhpehx).

Comment: Thanks to smooshie and user14111 for posting my previous queries. It's unfortunate I seem to have read a book that so few others have read/heard of. Some of the details may be off, but it was definitely inspired by folklore/creation myths. Think of the story of adam in the bible, book of genesis, where he is instructed to name all of the creatures. The story I'm thinking of is similar to that in nature, except adam is a boy and there are many gods instead of one.

Comment: Also, while suggestions like Cradoc's Quest and Neverending story are appreciated and the stories do seem similar on the outset, the fundamental story premises differ in nature.  Obviously, details from memory are going to differ from what the actual story is (and illustrated cover), but the basic details should still be present.

Comment: There is a general naming in Lafferty's "And Name My Name". Of course that's not what you're looking for, because it's a short story, and because it's a man doing the naming.

Comment: I thought in the Bible Adam had to name every living creature.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your assistance, but it looks like resources for this question have run out. I am continuing to email librarians across the United States. I am almost finished emailing every public library in Connecticut. 43 states left to go.

Comment: @Timewarp I know this goes without saying, please return with the answer. This is very intriguing.

Comment: Emailing *every* public library? You must have really liked this book.

Comment: Is there any possibility the book was translated from French? I remember reading a short review of a book that sounded similar to what you're describing, yeaaaaars ago in a teen's magazine. I remember the excerpt containing a lot of sound-based figures of speech, reading almost like prose poetry. Something about an antelope. If that sounds like your book... where do I find old issues of that magazine from 2000-2005? Libraries will have purged them already.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not Neverending Story? The characters in the story are being erased because the child-like empress needs a new name and no one in their world can give names, so they summon a boy reading the book to their world to rename the child-like empress. He then goes about defining things in their world, and creating new creatures. So, are you sure that is not The Neverending Story?

Comment: Can you provide any snippets of text that suggest similarity?

Comment: “Only the right name gives beings and things their reality. A wrong name makes everything unreal. That's what lies do.” 
― Michael Ende, The Neverending Story

Comment: “The Nothing is spreading," groaned the first. "It's growing and growing, there's more of it every day, if it's possible to speak of more nothing. All the others fled from Howling Forest in time, but we didn't want to leave our home. The Nothing caught us in our sleep and this is what it did to us."

"Is it very painful?" Atreyu asked. 

"No," said the second bark troll, the one with the hole in his chest. "You don't feel a thing. There's just something missing. And once it gets hold of you, something more is missing every day. Soon there won't be anything left of us.”

Comment: You can press here to [edit] them into your answer